# What happens if three defenders sack together?

Tags: american-football, nfl

I learned that if two players sack cooperatively, each defender gets 0.5 sacks in their statistics.

Then what happens if three players make a sack together?
Is it 0.333 sacks, or still 0.5 sacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NFL when multiple players sack the QB, they're all awarded a half a sack, regardless of how many players have been involved.

Here's explanation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarterback_sack#Statistical_record_rules)

> A player will receive credit for half of a sack when multiple players contribute to the sacking of a quarterback, even if more than two players contributed.

Note that a sack is not a rule. Rather a term for when a QB is taken down behind the line of scrimmage. So since it's a statistical term, you won't find an answer in usual sources like the NFL rules handbook.

Comment: The [NFL Guide for Statisticans](https://www.nflgsis.com/gsis/documentation/stadiumguides/guide_for_statisticians.pdf) does exist though... but is unfortunately silent on this subject.

Comment: yeah I found that too! It does talk about sacks, but not half sacks.

Comment: It mentions the two-defender case specifically, but not three or more (though even for two defenders, it only says the sack is divided equally, not that each defender gets half a sack). I'd say the Wikipedia page needs a [citation needed] flag on the claim that more than 2 defenders can be credited with half a sack.

Comment: Agreed wikipedia def needs citation, I was hoping to use one of the citations already on that page. The ones I checked were deadends. That being said, as an NFL fan I know that's the right answer. I tried to find a reputable source that explicitly mentions the scenario with more than 2 defenders, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Maybe someone can find an example of a games's box score where the total number of sacks by the defense is a half-integer.